# How can a plotly legend entry be put on two lines (\n in legend text)?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

I would like to split my legend text into two lines.  This would help increase the width of the plot and reduce the width of the legend.  However, when I use \n, it gets replaced with a space.  Is there a way to split the text into two lines?

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import plot
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 100)
y = np.random.normal(size=100)

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        name='A very long\nlegend entry',
        x=x,
        y=y,
        showlegend=True,
        mode='lines',
        line={'color': 'Black'}))

fig.update_layout(
        legend={
            'x': 1.01,
            'y': 0.5})

plot(fig)
```

[image: \n in legend text]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Trace names are interpreted as pseudo-HTML so you can use `<br>` instead of `\n` for newlines: `name='A very long<br>legend entry'`.